# Understanding ``components_`` of PCA (sklearn)?

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

Might someone explain me the variable `components_` of PCA(sklearn). The official URL of sklearn (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) does confuse me.

So I have an original dataset with 1000 features called `df`.

I did:

```
my_pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
my_pca.fit_transform (df)
my_pca.components_.shape # (2, 1000)
```

Can I interpret each element of `component_` as the influence of the original feature to each PCA-value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you compute PCA you basically compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the (correlation or covariance) matrix.

So actually you could compute up to 1000 eigenvectors. When you `set n_components=2` 
you implicitly say that you want to compute only the first two eigenvectors (the ones with the largest eigenvalues associated to them)

the `components_` contains these eigenvectors.

They are important because they encode your projection rule. They allow you to go from your initial space where the samples in `df` lay to the reduced two dimensional space by applying simple matrix multiplication.

```
proyected_sample = a_sample * np.transpose( my_pca.components_ )
```